# tensorflow serving: failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:9000'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have installed and configured tensorflow serving on an "AWS t2.large Ubuntu 14.04" server.

When I attempt to [test the server with the mnist_client utility](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) by executing the command, `bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client --num_tests=1000 --server=localhost:9000`, I receive the following error message:

`E0605 05:03:54.617558520    1232 tcp_client_posix.c:191]     failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:9000': timeout occurred`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of anything like this, but did note that (at least with other test clients) when the server was not ready/up yet, requests would timeout. So my guess is that the server is not up yet or perhaps in some other bad state.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem before. The root cause is `mnist_client` was run in my local machine instead of the server, because the command connects to localhost `bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client --num_tests=1000 --server=localhost:9000`

It succeeds when I run `mnist_client` utility in the server.